# Java program to build and run a maven project

Tags: java, maven

I was trying to create a java application that automatically build my project.Is it possible to create a java program to run a maven project?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, but why? Usually you'd use a build server like Jenkins to do that. (Except running it maybe)

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it?

Comment: But i want to create a progrm that schedule a job in my vm to run my projects frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below approach to start:

1. Create a batch/shell file to build your project using mvn/ant/gradle
   command. You would need Maven/Ant/Gradle installed in your system
   and environment variable needs to be setup properly.
2. Run This batch/shell file using java by taking advantage of Runtime
   Class. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
3. To schedule your java program, Use ExecutorService or Quartz. Or you
   can take advantage of Operating System Schedulers as well.

Hope this helps.